# Monkeypatching a function namespace

Tags: python

Inspired by ["Define @property on function"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50477609/674039), I tried to override a function's namespace:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         if item == 'k2':
...             return 'v2'
...         return super().__getitem__(item)
...     
>>> def f():
...     pass
... 
... 
>>> f.__dict__ = MyDict({'k1': 'v1'})
>>> 
>>> f.k1
'v1'
>>> f.k2
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'k2'
```

Why can `f.k1` resolve, but `f.k2` can't?

Comment: Why not overload [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) instead? Also, unless I'm mistaken `__getitem__` overloads the index `[]` operator; I think what you were looking for was `__getattribute__`.

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge - I'm not so sure about that. The function's `__getattribute__` (actually, its `tp_getattro` slot) should end up doing a getitem on the dict.

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge: To make (most) special methods (begin and end with `__`) work, they have to be defined on the class itself, not per-instance. As the OP's linked question's answers note, functions themselves are instances of the shared, immutable class `function`; you can't add a custom `__getattr__` to the class at all, and even if adding `__getattr__` works per-instance, there's a decent chance that might get fixed on a subsequent release to improve performance (since special methods are documented as being class level, not instance level anyway, it's not a big back compat concern).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Any feedback from the 2 downvoters?

Comment: There's really nothing special about `FunctionType` here, and it seems to be confusing quite a few of the people responding, so… maybe it's worth changing the example to a different type?

Comment: @abarnert There is something special about `FunctionType` here: the usual way of controlling attribute access (putting descriptors on the type) is not available.

Comment: @wim OK, that’s true; using `FunctionType` avoids people saying “Why don’t you just make a subclass”. So I guess it’s a tradeoff; to avoid one source of irrelevant answers and comments, you have to pick a different source of irrelevant answers and comments. (Although if PEP 575 goes through, you’ll need a different example anyway…)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version: Because CPython's `PyDict_GetItem` function isn't subclass friendly (it's not intended to be, to be clear; `PyDict_*` functions are all specialized to `PyDict_Object` itself, not generalized mappings).

Long version: Retrieving an attribute invokes `PyObject_GetAttr`. For classes which don't explicitly define a custom `tp_getattro` or `tp_getattr` (and [`PyFunction_Type` does not](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/funcobject.c#L628)), this ends up [calling `PyObject_GenericGetAttr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/object.c#L1124). Assuming nothing is found on the class itself, `PyObject_GenericGetAttr` (well, the private API function that implements it) [retrieves `__dict__` as normal, then calls `PyDict_GetItem` to retrieve the value](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/object.c#L1092). `PyDict_GetItem` explicitly uses `dict`'s C-level internals to perform the access, bypassing any custom `__getitem__` you might have defined. So your custom `__getitem__` is never invoked; for all practical purposes, your `dict` subclass is just a `dict`.

I originally hoped that you *might* be able to make this particular case work via [the officially supported `__missing__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__missing__#object.__missing__), but it turns out that's only invoked when the equivalent of `__getitem__` (`dict_subscript`) is invoked, not through the C level direct access APIs like `PyDict_GetItem` (which don't go through `dict_subscript` at all).

Basically, CPython seems to have made a choice to prioritize performance over complete flexibility here. Any `dict` subclass used as `__dict__` will be accessed as if it were a plain `dict` (which might get a little screwy if the subclass is doing some magic to store one value while pretending it stores a different value, since the magic is bypassed), and all mappings that aren't `dict` subclasses are rejected at time of assignment (you get a `TypeError` when you try to assign them to `f.__dict__`).

Comment: It does seem to be a CPython weirdness. `f.k2` is working normally on pypy.

Comment: This seems bug in CPython to me. They use PyDict_* API calls to access the dict, rather than the abstract PyMapping_* calls - therefore, they shouldn't allow to set `__dict__` to a subclass in the first place.

Comment: @wim If they used `PyMapping_*` calls, they'd allow any arbitrary mapping, not just `dict` subclasses. The point of allowing `dict` subclasses is to allow things like `OrderedDict`, `defaultdict`, and `Counter`—which don't override `__getitem__`.

Comment: @wim: Agreed. The one quirk that might justify it is that `PyDict_CheckExact` (which would prohibit subclasses) would also prohibit `collections.OrderedDict` (which is a subclass, but fully compatible with `dict` as of 3.5, when it was reimplemented in C and made largely API compatible with `dict`). Using `OrderedDict` for `__dict__` is kind of nice since it means your attributes iterate in a defined order (and in fact, in 3.6/3.7, making `dict` itself ordered was a justified by how nice this feature is). Blocking `dict` subclasses would prevent 3.5 code from having ordered attributes.

Comment: @abarnert: That said, none of the features of `defaultdict` or `Counter` would be used when implicitly accessed via `__dict__` (their hooks are bypassed too), so it's not a huge benefit (unless you're doing something terrible like alternating direct access to the instance stored `__dict__` and indirect access via attribute lookups).

Comment: @ShadowRanger The only real point of using `defaultdict` or `Counter` would be that you could share the same value used explicitly as a `Counter` in one place, and used as a namespace of some object in another place. (For example, if you wanted a "auto-dict" perl-style via recursive `defaultdict`, and you also wanted an "attr-dict" JS-style via assigning the object as its own `__dict__`… well, you'd deserve to be shot, but assuming you survived that shooting, you would have provided the best example I can think of that isn't `OrderedDict`…)

Comment: @ShadowRanger (Also, that obviously should have said "don't _just_ override `__getitem__`".)

Answer (score -2):

The first sentence in the documentation for `__getitem__` reads:  "Called to implement evaluation of self[key]."  You are assuming (hoping) that the evaluation of `f.k1` performs the explicit operation `f.__dict__["k1"]`, but it doesn't.  If you put a print statement in the first line of `__getitem__` you will see that this function never gets called by your code.

I'm not sure why this is, but I suspect that it's for performance reasons.  In any case, I can't think of a good use case for replacing a function's `__dict__`.  There are way too many ways that can fail.

Comment: I think it's because the `type(f)` is `types.FunctionType` and special methods are not looked-up in the instance's dictionary, but the instance's class instead.

Comment: @martineau: No special methods on the function itself are involved here; we're replacing the instance's `__dict__` with a `dict` subclass, and that `dict` subclass has the special method (which is properly defined on the class, not the instance). Paul is on the right track; the operation performed is roughly like `dict.__getitem__(f.__dict__, 'k1')` (which would bypass `__getitem__` overloads anyway), except it's not really `__getitem__` it's more like `__cpython_internal_getitem_that_cant_be_overridden_and_doesnt_invoke_missing_hook__`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.